# C++ COM port related, how to trigger a action with specific cmd received from a COM port

Tags: c++, interface, port

I was creating a simple file for project testing purpose. Main function of the code is to send and recieved data through a virtual COM port.'ack' is supposed to trigger the program to send data, but I can only receive 'ack?????'.  Appreciate any helps.

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
     HANDLE hcom;
         hcom = CreateFile("COM5",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING
                        ,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    if (hcom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "fail to open port\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    SetupComm(hcom,1024,1024);
    DCB dcb;
    GetCommState(hcom,&dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = 9600;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = 0;
    dcb.StopBits = 1;
    SetCommState(hcom,&dcb);
    char data[]={01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08};//just something simple, trying to convert into hex then send to COM 
    char received[3];//trying to convert whatever received into char
    DWORD dwWrittenLen = 0;
    DWORD dwReadsize = 0;

    bool re = ReadFile(hcom,received,3,&dwReadsize,NULL);
    printf("%s", received);
   if(received == 'ack'){
        if(!WriteFile(hcom,data,1024,&dwWrittenLen,NULL))
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "fail！\n");
        }

        k++;

        printf("succeed！\n" ,k);
        Sleep(10*1000);  //send data every 10s
   }

    return 0;
```

}'

Comment: You don't "convert" between hex and `char`.    A value can be stored in a `char`, regardless of whether it is hex, octal, decimal, or binary.   But the value ten (as in number of toes a typical human has) can be written as `0xA` in hex, `012` in octal, `10` in decimal, and `b1010` in binary.   The value in each case is the same, but the encoding (e.g. how it is read or written to a file) is different.

Comment: `'ack'` looks odd. Lot of characters in that character.

Comment: @Peter, thx. Guess I have been focusing on the wrong thing.